# Compile ATL project with only Windows SDK 7.1

Tags: c++, build, atl, winapi

I have a project which needs to be compiled. It is compiled on our build server which I have only installed Windows SDK 7.1 on. I would like to not have to install an actual Visual Studio on this machine, but am getting an error "cannot find atlstr.h" file which I've just read is part of ATL which is part of Visual Studio.

Is there any way I can get this to compile without installing Visual Studio on the build server?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ATL is now freely available as a part of Windows Driver Kit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487438.aspx

Comment: Is it usable with the regular Windows SDK toolchain? I thought the WDK set up a special limited environment etc. for drivers?

Comment: @rubenvb: I know people use it to compile their WTL code with VC Express.

Comment: From the link provided: ATL is included in the WDK as a convenience for driver developers who need to create Windows applets for their drivers. ATL should not be used for software development beyond this scope.  The ATL that is available through Visual Studio provides a more complete and current set of libraries and should be used for development of software and web applications.

Answer (score 2):

No. ATL is a fundamental part of the non-free versions of MSVC.

Comment: Really? No other way? What a waste to have to install the whole IDE on a build machine. Thanks for the help though...

Comment: That used to be correct in the past, but not any more. ATL is a part of Windows WSDK now.

Comment: @Nemanja: The Windows SDK v7.1 does *NOT* contain ATL. The only versio ever containing an ATL version was the VS2003 Platform SDK, which is by now far obsolete. - But now I notice you meant WDK. Sorry

Comment: @rubenvb: Yes, I inserted an extra "S" in my comment and can't edit it now. Should be WDK, not WSDK.